# APR and 12th Root (Recursive Formulas)

Tags: recursion, finance

I was going over recursive formulas and interest rates with my students the other day and I stumbled across something that I wasn't suspecting. I remember watching the following video [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/x9e81a4f98389efdf:series/x9e81a4f98389efdf:geo-series-notation/v/geometric-series-sum-to-figure-out-mortgage-payments) awhile back and now notice at 1 minute in that this problem is mentioned by taking the twelfth roof of the number vs taking the APR and dividing it by 12. Which is it? I mean looking at it here makes me think that you just divide by [twelve](https://www.capitalone.com/learn-grow/money-management/how-to-calculate-apr-on-credit-card/) but it still feels wrong.

> Let's say your $APR=0.15$ and the balance you owe is $5000$. You have a minimum payment each payment of $100$ dollars. The amount you owe next month would be $C_{i+1}=(C_i-100)(1+0.15/12)$ where $C_0=5000$. Your monthly interest rate would be your APR divided by 12 as there are twelve months in a year.

Now, I assumed this was true for the longest time. However, consider the formula where $i$ is the number of years and $P$ is the principal one owe's on a loan. Ignoring the amount you pay each month implies $P_{i+1}=1.15P_i \implies P_i=1.15^i\cdot 5000$ where $P_o=5000$ (easily proven by induction). This implies $P_n=1.15^{n/12}\cdot 5000$ would hold where $n$ is the number of months. In other words, $P_n=(1.15^{1/12})^n\cdot 5000=(\sqrt[12]{1.15})^n\cdot 5000\implies P_{n+1}=\sqrt[12]{1.15}P_n$ where $P_0=5000$. So, then clearly $\sqrt[12]{1.15}=\text{monthly interest rate}$. This is surely a problem as the monthly interest rate cannot simply be calculated by dividing the number by $12$. So, why is the monthly interest rate on a credit card simply calculated by taking the number and dividing it by twelve? The two formulas give different results which is where I am confused because only one is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See the answer here by Jonathan Komar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134664/how-to-determine-the-monthly-interest-rate-from-an-annual-interest-rate/3103507

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the monthly interest rate from an annual interest rate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134664/how-to-determine-the-monthly-interest-rate-from-an-annual-interest-rate)

Answer (score 1):

Note $APR$ is really useless to see what's going on. By definition, $APR:=\text{monthly periodic interest rate}\cdot 12$. It has nothing to do with compounded interest; it's just defined to be as such. The monthly periodic interest rate is what is important as it is related to the $APY$ below.

As noted for the twelfth root, $APY=(1+\text{monthly periodic interest rate})^{12}-1$.

Note $\sqrt[12]{1+APY}=\sqrt[12]{(1+\text{monthly periodic interest rate})^{12}}=1+\text{monthly periodic interest rate}$

Also, $C_{i+1}=(C_i−100)(1+\text{monthly periodic interest rate})=(C_i−100)(1+APR/12)=(C_i−100)(\sqrt[12]{1+\text{APY}})$

Hence we can convert between $APY$ and $APR$ by the last two expressions of the last equation.